# How to create a Payment ID with the Monero RPC Wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, rpc, payment-id, integrated-address

What is the equivalent command for 'integrated_address' on the RPC interface?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i found the answer, it's 'make_integrated_address'.
See: https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#make_integrated_address